# Flutter Web Firestore Running Out of Memory - Provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web, provider

I have a very tricky situation, which I've reproduced in a demo.
I have a Provider of a user, with this method of updating the listeners:

```
class User extends ChangeNotifier {
...

  User({required this.uid}) {
    Database().getUser(uid).listen(
      (user) async {
        displayName = user?.displayName;
        email = user?.email;
        phoneNumber = user?.phoneNumber;
        photoURL = user?.photoURL;
        did = user?.did;
        interests = user?.interests;
        notifyListeners();
      },
      onError: (e) => print(e),
    );
  }
...
}
```

My main.dart starts like this:

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthState>.value(value: _authState),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeModel>(create: (_) => ThemeModel())
  ],
  child: Consumer<AuthState>(
    builder: (context, auth, child) {
      var user =
          auth.authUser == null ? null : User(uid: auth.authUser!.uid);
      return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<ZUser?>.value(
            value: zuser,
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp.router(...
```

This has been sufficient for my use case thus far.
Now, I wish to make an update to the interests field;
I have a DB widget that does:

```
  Future updateUser(String uid, Map<String, Object?> data) async {
    return userCollection.doc(uid).update(data);
  }
```

Where the userCollection is my collection in Firestore.
I call this class from my view widget, as:

```
ZWideButton(
  text: "Save",
  onPressed: () async {
    setState(() {
       _localEdit = false;
       _loading = true;
    });
    await user.saveInterests(_interests());
    setState(() => _loading = false);
  },
),
```

Where saveInterests is:

```
  Future saveInterests(List<String> interests) async {
    return _db.updateUser(uid, {"interests": interests});
  }
```

None of this presents any problem at first -- I can update the interests and it works fine. That is, until I keep updating the interests, and it gets slower and slower each time (the browser says the download time gets longer and longer) and seemingly my computer is eating up more and more memory until the webpage ultimately crashes.

Something of a memory leak appears to be happening, but I'm unsure what about flutter web and firebase could be causing it. I believe it may have to do with the Provider package not disposing appropriately. It does not seem to be the provider as I don't see the Widget being rebuilt over and over. Looking for some thoughts.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3617

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking; My issue is that my json deserializer was causing an infinite loop with the firebase listener